# Gold/Silver/Bronze badge icons appear to be cut off

Tags: bug

All the badge icons are cutoff, so they appear to be half-moons.

This appears to be happening everywhere on the main site where the little badge circles appear: at the top of the page next to my account, on every question and answer where the poster has earned at least one badge, etc.

This is only happening on the main site, not the meta site.

It is most obvious on the profile page where you select your next badge to track:

[image]

Comment: ugh, now that you mention it. CANNOT UNSEE....

Comment: This affects multiple sites. This has also been asked recently on main META: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314038/badge-icons-partially-hidden-on-some-sites-with-the-new-design

Comment: Well darn, if you ain't right!  I'm being mooned by my own badges.

Comment: This has been fixed. Announcement from main META: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314252/365152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will risk it and point out the obvious.

[image]

for classes .badge1 .badge2 and .badge3 CSS background-position is:

[image]

Should be more like:

[image]